# Checking user's network environment - Python application

Tags: python, windows, macos, pyodbc, pymssql

My Python application connects to a MSSQL database to verify some matter numbers, but this step is only necessary to assist with data integrity and does not bring the user any additional functionality.

The database is only accessible when on my office's local network. How do I check a user's environment during startup to see if this connection can be made?

I'm using pyodbc, but I also need this program to work on OS X, so I'm not importing that module until this check returns a positive result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket

mssql_server = 'foobar.example.not' # set this to your own value
s = socket.socket()
s.settimeout(3)
try:
    server = [x for x in socket.getaddrinfo(mssql_server,1433) if x[0]==2 ][0][-1]
except socket.gaierror:
    server = None
if server:
    try:
        s.connect(server)
    except (socket.timeout, socket.error):
        server = None
s.close()
```

... this should attempt to find an IPv4 address for your server (using the first one returned by `getaddrinfo()`) and then attempt to connect to the MS SQL TCP port (1433 by default) on that system.  (Yes, change 1433 if your server is on a different port).  If there's a timeout or any other socket error reported on the attempt, then server is set to `None`.  Otherwise you probably have an MS SQL server that you could access.

Comment: This'll be my backup plan if I can't get beargle's answer to work. Thanks Jim.

Comment: Your question tag indicates SQL Server, which is likely running on default port 1433.

Comment: Ah. My mistake, I'd just answered a different question which was MySQL rather than MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the host is available using ping before import:

```
import subprocess

host = "<hostname>"
# add sample text for ping resolution errors here
errors = ("could not find", "unreachable")

ping = "ping {0}".format(host)
(stdout, stderr) = subprocess.Popen(ping, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

# stdout is a byte string and must be decoded before compare
if not any(error in stdout.decode("utf-8") for error in errors):
    import pyodbc
    .....
```

Comment: I think this will work! I'm going to test it out tomorrow at work and see how it goes. Thanks for your help, beargle!